# Oracle | Unable to exlude database link while export of a schema

Tags: oracle

can you please advise how to exclude DB links when exporting DB schema by:

```
exp userid=USER/PASS@server File=/export/schema_20170605.dmp
```

I do not need them in the dump but need to keep them on the server 11g.

When trying to export it as is getting error:

```
. exporting database links EXP-00106: Invalid Database Link Passwords
EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully
```

I have tried also expdp which could works but it requires dedicated folder directly on the DB server.

Thanks, Reddy

Comment: Why not just create a directory and use datapump? There is no natural way to exclude specific objects using EXP/IMP. Even excluding direct tables is hacky at best. Use datapump and your problems are over.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using exp version 10.2.0.1.0 against server version 11.2.0.4.0.
Using newer exp version 11.2.0.2.0 fixed it for me.